# Can MS Dynamics be placed in an iframe

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to know if MS Dynamics can be included into an iFrame. We would like to integrate within a call center desktop MS Dynamics, and this would require that we can place MS Dynamics into an iframe. I have done a search, but I can only seem to find iframes within MS dynamics but not the other way around. In addition, MS Dynamics does not seem to provide  developer accounts to test for free.

If anyone knows the answer I would really appreciate.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot add Dynamics 365 (crm) as Iframe in your website. This is not allowed from Microsoft. This is basically due to cross scripting and authentication.

To solve your purpose you can use portals. Portals act as website and it will leverage/build on dynamics data (dataverse)

[Look at this thread which mentions somewhat similar topic](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=b15e8d93-3ebb-45cf-9028-8601c0f7d2d6&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer)